# How to convert Iterator<? extends Person> to Iterable?

Tags: java, generics

The tricky part is that the type includes a upper bounded wildcard.

The Java 8 conversion does not work:

```
Iterator<? extends Person> it = null;
Iterable<? extends Person> it2 = () -> it;
```

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<capture#2-of ? extends Person> to Iterator<Person>`

Comment: You can safely cast a `Iterable<? extends Person>` to a `Iterable<Person>`, because there are no consumer methods on it.

Comment: why not use [Iterator.forEachRemaining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A helper method can solve this without the need to suppress warnings or cast anything:

```
Iterator<? extends Number> iterator = null;
Iterable<? extends Number> iterable = toIterable(iterator);

public static <T> Iterable<T> toIterable(Iterator<T> it) {
    return () -> it;
}
```

Comment: exactly. this is called a `wildcard capture`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: Is a simple iterator > iterable like this provided in Java standard library anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get this iterator from?
As far as I know the only way to obtain `Iterator<E>` is through `Iterable<T>.iterator()`.
Anyways, if you have an `Iterator`, you can reconstruct the `Iterable` using a `while` loop:

```
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it2.append(it.next); // just fill a new Iterable (if you can)
    }
```

And if you read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), something could get clearer.

Comment: How about `LinkedList<T>.descendingIterator()`

Answer (score 0):

A simple wrapper class could do this.

```
class IteratorIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    final Iterator<T> it;

    public IteratorIterable(Iterator<T> it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return it;
    }
}

public void test() {
    Iterator<? extends Person> it = null;
    for ( Person person : new IteratorIterable<>(it)) {
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Note that this will almost certainly fail if it is used more than once.